# Python 3 : Run function on particular subdirectory

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

Need to create a file with particular subdirectory, the subdirectory name is "mydir".

├── dir_1 
├── dir_2
│   └── mydir

**Code:**

```
import os
import glob

directory_to_check = glob.glob("/Users/name/Documents/python/delete/*/")

def my_function(directory):
      print("Listing: " + directory)
      print("\t-" + "\n\t-".join(os.listdir("."))) 


directories = [os.path.abspath(x[0]) for x in os.walk(directory_to_check)]
directories.remove(os.path.abspath(directory_to_check))

folder = "mydir"
if os.path.isdir(folder):

      for i in folder:
            os.chdir(i)       
            with open("file.txt", 'w+') as f:
                  f.write("file is opened for business")
```

Error:

`Exception has occurred: TypeError expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list File "/Users/name/Documents/python/delete/delete_test.py", line 11, in <module> directories = [os.path.abspath(x[0]) for x in os.walk(directory_to_check)]`

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback!

Comment: You can maybe try passing `f"{folder}/file.txt"` instead of `"file.txt"`, I think it's more elegant than changing the current directory with `os.chdir(i)`

Comment: @KlausD. - I have updated.

Comment: Replace the `os.path.abspath` with `print` and you will see why it does not work.

Comment: with help of this ```glob.glob("/Users/name/Documents/python/delete/*/")[0]``` it will work on one folder, but need to execute on particular folder name "mydir"